# Getting date in format "Monday, October 1st, 2013" from CURRENT_DATE

Tags: php

I have an SQL `INSERT` statement putting in `CURRENT_DATE` to one of my tables. I want to print this on a page, but instead of using the ####-##-## format, I'd like it to be formatted like Day, Month Date, Year like in the title of the question. I can for sure `explode()` the table element and display the month, date, and year properly, but what of the day of that specific date? Ex.

```
$datearray = explode("-",$date["current"]);
if ($datearray[1] == '01') {
    $month = 'January';
} else if ($datearray[1] == '02') {
    $month = 'February';
... ... ...
... ... ...
... ... ...
} else {
    $month = 'December';
```

Surely there's an easier way to do this? How do I find the day of the week corresponding to a certain date?

I wanted to add that I'm not entirely sure if I should be using `CURRENT_DATE` for this purpose. If there is an alternative, I cannot find it. It would be swell if there was a column attribute something like `DATE_IN_WORDS`, but I think this is wishful thinking and being a bit silly on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$datearray = explode("-",$date["current"]); 
date('l, F dS, Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $datearray[1], $datearray[2], $datearray[0]));
```

Try this!

Edit:

Or even easier:

```
date('l, F dS, Y', strtotime($date["current"]));
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much. I think I might forego the "Monday, Tuesday, ..." thing since this looks nice already. edit; I mistook that l for a one, now I have the day as well. Cheers!

Comment: d is two digit with leading zero, j is without

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` can convert your string from db value to unix timestamp and `date('l, F dS, Y',$result_of_strtotime)` will do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = new DateTime($date["current"]);
echo $date->format('l, F jS, Y');
```